# Per group identities with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am using NHibernate 3.3.2 (for the first time) and I am trying to create the following table, so that the ID is the unique table/entity identifier and the sequence is a unique identity per group, in the table example clubs 123, 232 and 444 are groups.

```
ID Club Sequence
1  123  1
2  123  2
3  232  1
4  232  2
5  444  1
6  123  3
```

I want the Inserts to be just with the club category, both identities will be automatic.

Can this be done? And if so, how can I do it?

Comment: There is no mention of an intended object design. How do you plan on teaching the RDBMS to generate the sequence numbers like that?

Comment: the intended object design will have the same regular properties plus the Sequence property which will be an int. the second part of your comment is exactly my question.

Comment: Then you should maybe add tags for sql and your RDBMS. I thought you were asking how to make NHibernate not interfere with the numbers generated by the DB.

Comment: Maybe this goes to show that I don't really understand... in my view I can set ID as Identity, and now I want to set Sequence as Identity per group, as described, is this at all possible through nHibernate or must I do it manually?

Comment: The phrase "both identities will be automatic" sounded to me like you already had this covered, and that the question was something else. As I understand it now, your true question is "What is the nicest way to generate the values in the Sequence column according to this pattern?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is something like:

> What is the nicest way to generate the values in the Sequence column according to this pattern?

Then here are some hints:

- To have the DB generate the Sequence column, I think you need to look at a trigger-based solution. The "groups" of which you speak means nothing to the DB unless you create some (SQL-)code to handle it. You might want to create a stored procedure that generates the number and then an INSERT-trigger.
- NHibernate can be told to ignore the column for INSERT and just read back the value generated by the DB. See [Generated Properties](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-generated) in the NHibernate reference.
- The structure you describe is similar to what a mapping of a list in NHibernate would generate, if you drop the Id column. A collection is always owned by something, so this could be a solution if you have a collection owned by Club. The Club column would then point to the collection owner, and the Sequence would be the index in the list. (I'm assuming the table is supposed to contain more columns, which would then be the elements in the list.)

I think what you need to do is think about what *object model* makes sense to you problem. Then design the tables to match that. NHibernate is good at handling existing legacy table models, but if you're starting from scratch it makes sense to create the model first.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to specify a formula in your property mapping that generates the max sequence if performing an insert. Or you could change your entity to generate a sequence number if one doesnt exist.

Comment: can you specify about the formula? an example or a link to look for something similar?